# Trying to implement jcifs and UniAddress and getting NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, jcifs

I am using JCIFS (http://jcifs.samba.org/). My code is simple and taken from the Login.java example:

```
import jcifs.*;
import jcifs.smb.*;

public class netp {
    public static void main( String argv[] ) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("START");

     String ip = "10.0.0.1";
     String domain = "domain";
     String user = "user";
     String pass = "pass";

    UniAddress dc = UniAddress.getByName( ip );
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication( domain + ";" + user + ":" + pass );
    SmbSession.logon( dc, auth );

     System.out.println("END");

     return;
    }
}
```

Compiling this works if I do this:

```
javac -cp jcifs-krb5-1.3.17.jar netp.java
```

However, if I run it like this:

```
java -cp jcifs-1.3.17.jar netp
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class netp
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've uploaded the complete source code here:

```
https://www.box.com/s/po4frdmy0obqiroy9anp
```

Note: I am doing this all in Windows.

Comment: Is there a `netp.class` in your current directory after the `javac` step?

Comment: Argh! You're missing the `krb5` part in the `java` step!

Comment: in what package is netp class?

Comment: Also try without the `"..."` just to exhaust the possible error causes...

Comment: just add the name of the package before netp, and if the path to jcifs is correct and you are running the command "java.." from correct directory it will work. see my answer to what *correct* means.

Comment: Once more into the breach, as they say: You must add the current directory to the `-cp` argument and make sure the JARs names are *valid*: `java -cp .;jcifs-krb5-1.3.17.jar netp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your myJavaApp class is in some package and you have omitted the package name in addition to not setting class path at all.

My directory structure for testing:

```
.
\--- jcifs-1.3.17.jar
\--- testapp
     \--- myJavaApp.java
```

I compiled it like this:

```
javac -cp jcifs-1.3.17.jar testapp/myJavaApp.java
```

which gave myJavaApp.class in testapp folder as expected. I have run it on linux like this:

```
java -cp .:jcifs-1.3.17.jar testapp.myJavaApp
```

and on windows like this:

```
java -cp .;jcifs-1.3.17.jar testapp.myJavaApp
```

It throwed

```
jcifs.util.transport.TransportExceptionjava
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

which means that the myJavaApp had run succesfully.

If we remove the testapp directoy, e.g.

```
.
\--- jcifs-1.3.17.jar
\--- myJavaApp.java
```

it compiles with:

```
 javac -cp jcifs-1.3.17.jar myJavaApp.java
```

and on linux runs with:

```
java -cp .:jcifs-1.3.17.jar myJavaApp
```

for windows

```
java -cp .;jcifs-1.3.17.jar myJavaApp
```

EDIT:

all java[c] commands were run from root(.) / testing directory

EDIT^2:

I have downloaded your code and placed myself in netp directory. Compiled the code like this:

```
C:\netp>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javac.exe" -cp jcifs-krb5-1.3.17.jar netp.java
```

and succesfully run it like this:

```
C:\netp>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe" -cp .;jcifs-krb5-1.3.17.jar netp
```

it outputs:

```
START
END
```

Comment: Will try all of this now, but as an FYI, here is my code --> https://www.box.com/s/po4frdmy0obqiroy9anp

Comment: I've now changed what I had and I am running it exactly like this, but I still get: Error: Could not find or load main class netp.java ... for some reason it's not picking it up and I can't see why.

Comment: "Could not find or load main class netp.java" when you compile you put ".java". when you run there is no file type just full class name (in your case - just netp) see my last update

Comment: So the problem has to do with PATH issues. If I run it the way you suggested, it works. I will keep investigating and post the final cause of the problem when I'm done! But thank you Linski! You helped a lot!

Comment: in order too run just "java[c]" from your command line you must have some jre[jdk] pointed at in your [PATH variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) see what's in there, you may be pointing at "wrong" jdk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the jar on class path too when you run the program:

```
java -cp jcifs_1.3.17/jcifs-1.3.17.jar myJavaApp
```

Comment: Doesnt work... says: Error: Could not find or load main class myJavaApp

Comment: @RD is the myJavaApp.class file in the current directory?

Comment: Yes it is! To me it looks like its somehow not picking up the JAR file, but I can't understand why. It looks like I'm doing everything right, but no luck...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding current directory to the classpath as well:

```
java -cp .:jcifs-krb5-1.3.17/jcifs-krb5-1.3.17.jar myJavaApp
```

If you're on Windows, replace the colon with semi-colon: `java -cp .;jcifs-krb5-1.3.17/jcifs-krb5-1.3.17.jar myJavaApp`

Cheers,

Comment: I'm on a linux system and using `:` as CP separator works for me. If you're on a Windows box you might want to try with semi-colon/`;` and enclose the CP in `"..."`: `java -cp ".;jcifs_1.3.17/jcifs-1.3.17.jar" myJavaApp`.

Comment: Incidentally, how did `bruteHack` get into the game?

Comment: Sorry, jumping between difference versions. Will upload the full code in a bit.